CalendarDatePicker null value is 100 years in the past
I have a WinUI application and use the CalendarDatePicker element. I have a binding on a ListView and the selected item. Unfortunately, a default date 100 years in the past is always selected. What am I doing wrong?
If the DateTime Value is null, I expect the date to be empty.
In the converter I have already tried the case with return null; for the conversion from DateTime to DateTimeOffset.
I have also already tried @Asier Peña's solution with the CalendarDatePickerEx class in the following stackoverflow question CalendarDatePicker Binding Null Value. Unfortunately without success.
The second solution with the change from Binding to x:Bind does not work, because AssetTV.SelectedItem.PurchaseDate gives the error message that this does not exist:
WMC1110    Invalid binding path 'AssetTV.SelectedItem.PurchaseDate' : Property 'PurchaseDate' not found on type 'Object'.
In the AssetPage.xaml i have a TreeView
<!--  Asset tree  -->
<TreeView
    x:Name="AssetTV"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Margin="0,5,0,0"
    AllowDrop="True"
    CanDragItems="True"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind _assetItem}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:AssetItem">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChildItems}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{x:Bind Model}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Manufacturer}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

In the same AssetPage.xaml I have two CalendarDatePicker that reference the currently selected TreeView item:
<CalendarDatePicker
    x:Name="InstallationDateCDP"
    Grid.Row="11"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Margin="5"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Date="{Binding SelectedItem.InstallationDate, ElementName=AssetTV, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}"
    DateFormat="{}{day.integer}. {month.full} {year.full}"
    Header="Purchase date"
    IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=AssetTV, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource CountToBooleanConverter}}"
    PlaceholderText="asdf" />
<CalendarDatePicker
    x:Name="PurchaseDateCDP"
    Grid.Row="11"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="5"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Date="{Binding SelectedItem.PurchaseDate, ElementName=AssetTV, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}"
    DateFormat="{}{day.integer}. {month.full} {year.full}"
    Header="Purchase date"
    IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=AssetTV, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource CountToBooleanConverter}}" />

I have a class called AssetItem.cs
(I use the NuGet Package PropertyChanged.Fody to automatically implement the property notification):
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Test.Models;

public class AssetItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string? AssetItemType { get; set; }
    public string? Model { get; set; }
    public string? Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string? SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Specification { get; set; }

    public string? ItemStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string? Notes { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<AssetItem> ChildItems { get; set; }

    public AssetItem()
    {
        this.ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<AssetItem>();
    }
}

And for the conversion of DateTime to DateTimeOffset I have the following Converter:
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace Test.Helpers;
public class TimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null)
           return new DateTimeOffset(((DateTime)value).ToUniversalTime());
        else
            return null;
    }

    public object? ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null)
            return ((DateTimeOffset)value).DateTime;
        else
            return null;
    }
}


Why are you calling ToUniversalTime() on the DateTime in the converter? Remove this.
